# Merge Hot and Cold Observable with buffer

Tags: java, android, kotlin, rx-java2, reactive-streams

I have 2 sources of data.

1. A service call which gets the current state of a list of items
2. A stream of updates to these items

I am trying to merge them in a way that I don't lose any of the updates while making the service call.

I made a simple test to experiment with that I think shows what I want

```
private val coldObservable = Observable.just(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
private val subject = PublishSubject.create<Int>()
private val hotObservable = subject.hide()

@Test
fun test() {
    subject.onNext(10)

    val test = Flowable.concat(
            coldObservable.toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER), hotObservable.toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER)
    )
            .doOnSubscribe { subject.onNext(20) }
            .test()

    test.await(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    test.assertNotComplete()
    test.assertNotTerminated()
    subject.onComplete()
    test.assertComplete()
    test.assertValues(1,2,3,4,5)
}
```

As is, this test passes. But what I really want is

```
test.assertValues(1,2,3,4,5,10,20)
```

I thought the backpressure would easily let me hold on to the emissions but I guess it doesn't because it's not subscribed to.

Is there no way to merge these 2 sources into a single stream?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that has a similar effect to what I am looking for.
It stores the live data and then processes it once the service call has finished

```
@Test
fun test2() {
    val randomString = "abc123"
    val realLog = ConcurrentHashMap<String, Boolean>()

    var isLive = false

    val subject = PublishSubject.create<Pair<String, Boolean>>()

    val subscription = subject.hide()
            .doOnNext {
                if (isLive) {
                    realLog[it.first] = it.second
                } else {

                    realLog[it.first+ randomString] = it.second
                }
            }.subscribe()

    subject.onNext(Pair("one", false))

    val coldTest = Observable.just("one","two","three")
            .map { Pair(it, true) }
            .doOnSubscribe {
                subject.onNext(Pair("twenty", false))
            }
            .doOnNext{
                realLog[it.first] = it.second
            }
            .doOnComplete {
                val iterator = realLog.keys.iterator()
                while(iterator.hasNext()){
                    val oldKey = iterator.next()
                    if(oldKey.contains(randomString)){
                        val newKey = oldKey.removeSuffix(randomString)
                        realLog[newKey] = realLog[oldKey]!!
                        realLog.remove(oldKey)
                    }
                }
                isLive = true
                subject.onNext(Pair("Thirty", false))
            }
            .test()

    coldTest.awaitTerminalEvent()
    coldTest.assertComplete()

    Assert.assertFalse(realLog["Thirty"]!!)
```

It doesn't emit a single stream, i'm still not sure if this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand all of your code (new to rx myself). But your use case seems to be identical to one I had.

My use case was this (so you can decide if it is relevant): I used an HTTP request to get the initial state of a data structure. But a web socket stream kept sending updates to that data. If I first initialized the data structure, and then updated it with the stream, updates would have been lost in the short time span in between. So I needed to get the stream first, cache its update data while waiting for the HTTP request to return with the data structure, and then apply the backlog of updates from the stream (in the cache) on the data. And from there move along updating as data from socket comes in.

I don't know Kotlin, so in Java:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    //This one would correspond to the continuous stream of updates.
    //It sends Long, one each second
    Observable<Long> listUpdater = Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    //Acts as both observable and observer, that replays everything to its own
    //observers.
    Subject<Long> replaySubjbect = ReplaySubject.create();
    //Start getting items from listUpdater immediately
    listUpdater.subscribe(replaySubjbect);
    //To show that listUpdater moves along regardless of what you are doing, as would
    //be the case for example with a websocket.
    listUpdater.subscribe(i -> System.out.println("I am also watching, i=" + i));
    //This callable corresponds to whatever returns the initial state of the list,
    //for example some http request
    Callable<List<Long>> clbl = () -> Arrays.asList(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L);
    //This is where the merging takes place, although we are not using one of the merging
    //methods, but scanWith. 
    Observable<List<Long>> theStream = replaySubjbect.scanWith(clbl, (List<Long> list, Long l) -> {
        //This updater adds l to each element of the list
        System.out.println("I am adding " + l + " to each element in the list");
        return list.stream().mapToLong(k -> k + l).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());            
    });
    //Simulate a response time for the http request, or whatever it is the callable is doing
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    //Now we get the stream of lists, updated for each of the update data sent by the
    //original listUpdater
    theStream.subscribe(list -> System.out.println("theStream sent me this: " + list));
    //Just to see how it works, we sleep some more
    Thread.sleep(5000); 
}
```

This outputs:

```
I am also watching, i=0
I am also watching, i=1
I am also watching, i=2
theStream sent me this: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] <- cahce retrieval starts
I am adding 0 to each element in the list 
theStream sent me this: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] 
I am adding 1 to each element in the list 
theStream sent me this: [2, 3, 4, 5, 6] 
I am adding 2 to each element in the list 
theStream sent me this: [4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
I am also watching, i=3     
I am adding 3 to each element in the list <- from here on, update list as updates come in
theStream sent me this: [7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
I am also watching, i=4
I am adding 4 to each element in the list
theStream sent me this: [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
I am also watching, i=5
I am adding 5 to each element in the list
theStream sent me this: [16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
I am also watching, i=6
I am adding 6 to each element in the list
theStream sent me this: [22, 23, 24, 25, 26]
I am also watching, i=7
I am adding 7 to each element in the list
theStream sent me this: [29, 30, 31, 32, 33]
```

scanWith:
http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#scanWith-java.util.concurrent.Callable-io.reactivex.functions.BiFunction-

You could also use scan (supply initial data directly, instead of with a Callable):
http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#scan-R-io.reactivex.functions.BiFunction-